# List View not displaying remote images

Tags: android, android-listview, hashmap, android-image, simpleadapter

I am using a HashMap to display images and text in a listview via a simpleAdapter. Now this works fine with images from my R.drawable. But as soon as I retrieve the image as a bitmap from a remote source, it doesn't display the image. The image is being downloaded correctly and it displays fine when I display it on a image view. Here is my code for retrieving an image and storing it in a bitmap variable:

```
   user_picture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.widget89);
    java.net.URL img_value = null;
    try {
        img_value = new java.net.URL("http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/picture?type=small");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    user_picture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance
Jannik

Answer (score 0):

In recent projects, I have used the below class for fetching bitmaps and storing these in custom objects and using these for populating a ListView using an Adapter:

```
package com.octoshape.android.octopocplayer.playlist;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class BitmapDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]); 
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            return bm;
        } catch (IOException e) {}
            return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the Adapter:

```
private class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return playList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return playList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return (playList.get(position) instanceof String) ? ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_CHANNELSET
                    : ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_CHANNEL;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            // A separator cannot be clicked !
            return getItemViewType(position) != ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_CHANNELSET;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final int type = getItemViewType(position);

            // First, let's create a new convertView if needed. You can also
            // create a ViewHolder to speed up changes if you want ;)
            if (convertView == null) {
                final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                        .from(DemoPlayer.this);
                final int layoutID = type == ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_CHANNELSET ? R.layout.separator_list_item
                        : R.layout.video_list_item;
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutID, parent, false);
            }

            // We can now fill the list item view with the appropriate data.
            if (type == ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_CHANNELSET) {
                ((TextView) convertView).setText((String) getItem(position));
            } else {
                final Channel channel = (Channel) getItem(position);
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .setText(channel.getName());
                ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo))
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.default);

                if (channel.getChannelImage() != null)
                    ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.channellogo))
                            .setImageBitmap(channel.getChannelImage());
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```